# in Rails, can I change the belongs_to :symbol?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

example:

```
has_many :books
```

- will the     **:books**   be the method RAILS will create for me?
- if so, can I simply change that to something else? like **:notes** so I can use it with **User.notes** ????

Answer (score 3):

If you simply want to rename the method, but keep the model (ie. have a model named Book but the method called notes), you can use the class_name symbol:

```
has_many :notes, :class_name => :Book
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, :books is a model created for you. This model corresponds to Model Book.rb, If you want to change the ":books" to ":notes" you have to create the Model Note. You can create the Model note with this command (in the terminal):

> rails g model Note name:string, description:string parameter:type

After you have change the relationship between Models, for example you have the Model Book.rb and the Model Person.rb and you want to change Book to Note, then:

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base     
  attr_accessible :id, :number

  has_many :books #delete this
  has_many :notes #add this
end
```

book.rb

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base     
  attr_accessible :id, :name

  belongs_to :user #delete this
end
```

Delete relationship in Book model and add in Note model.

note.rb

```
class Note < ActiveRecord::Base     
  attr_accessible :id, :name

  belongs_to :user #add this
end
```

Comment: You don't need to change the model just for the method to be renamed.